# How much should chickens be fed?

Tags: chickens

We’ve recently acquired four six-month-old chickens, and my question is: how much food and water will they need every day?

I’ve heard (albeit not from a *particularly* reputable source) that sometimes if you give them too much, they’ll eat it anyway and get sick. So how much food and water should you give them every day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without question; Water should be available 24/7 there are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Depending on the solution, you will need to clean the water bowl/supply daily to weekly.

Personally I have normally provided food 24/7 there a number of feeders available. I like gravity feeders where you just add more to top, the chickens take it from the bottom.

If you are going to allow your chickens out of the coop, to hunt bugs and plants during the day, you may need/want a way to get them back in the coop in the evening. In that case feed them in the evening.  It is pretty easy to train them to come get the good food at night time. Even then I would normally keep food available in the coop 24/7.

I have never seen an issue from too much food for chickens.  Underfeeding, particularly for laying hens can have dire consequences.